# Did I "kill" texsys.cfg by chance? - and what to do about it?

Tags: miktex, compiling, texmaker

**Situation**
About 90 min ago I tried a compile (with a KOMA script) AND updating MikTex simultaneously on Windows, which probably was a bad idea.

Now, when trying to compile even a simple .tex file with TexMaker, it asks for permission to install `texsys.cfg` ... and runs some processes (see screenshot)  happily without noticeable end (i.e. close to running forever).

Killing TexMaker and all its processes, deinstalling and reinstalling didn't change anything. Next would be to try deinstalling MikTex.

**Question:**
But before doing so: Am I on the right track? Any locks some process may have put? Will a simple copy of that file (if I can find it) do the job? // What to do?

BTW, `texsys.cfg` can't be found on my system. Only these two are there:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

[image: process list]

---

**From comments:**

I extracted below the relevant excerpt from `miktex-console.log` . It matches both time (18:10) and cabohahs guess about `ltxbase`. Several times it says:

- Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.
- The process can't access the file, as it's used by another process.

```
2023-02-18 18:10:44,994+0100 INFO  mainwindow - extracting files from latex-graphics-dev.tar.lzma...
2023-02-18 18:10:45,094+0100 INFO  miktex-console.packagemanager - installing package ltxbase
2023-02-18 18:10:45,094+0100 INFO  mainwindow - downloading https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ltxbase.tar.lzma...
2023-02-18 18:10:45,094+0100 INFO  miktex-console.packagemanager - going to download https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ltxbase.tar.lzma
2023-02-18 18:10:45,163+0100 INFO  mainwindow - 0.23 MB, 26.01 Mbit/s
2023-02-18 18:10:46,883+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.

2023-02-18 18:10:46,883+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Function: DeleteFileW
2023-02-18 18:10:46,883+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Result: 32
2023-02-18 18:10:46,883+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Data: path="C:\Users\whoever\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX2\tex\latex\base\latex.ltx"
2023-02-18 18:10:46,883+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:320
2023-02-18 18:10:48,287+0100 INFO  mainwindow - extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
2023-02-18 18:10:48,349+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.

2023-02-18 18:10:48,349+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Function: DeleteFileW
2023-02-18 18:10:48,349+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Result: 32
2023-02-18 18:10:48,349+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Data: path="C:\Users\whoever\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX2\tex\latex\base\latex.ltx"
2023-02-18 18:10:48,349+0100 ERROR miktex-console.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:320
2023-02-18 18:10:48,619+0100 ERROR mainwindow - Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:320: Windows API error 32: Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.
(path="C:\Users\whoever\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX2\tex\latex\base\latex.ltx")
2023-02-18 18:13:11,681+0100 WARN  main - session.use_count() == 8
2023-02-18 18:13:11,681+0100 INFO  main - finishing with exit code 0
2023-02-18 18:13:56,774+0100 INFO  main - starting: MiKTeX Console 4.8 (MiKTeX 22.10)
2023-02-18 18:14:09,850+0100 INFO  mainwindow - checking for updates...
2023-02-18 18:14:09,865+0100 INFO  miktex-console.packagemanager - searching for updateable packages
2023-02-18 18:14:09,880+0100 INFO  miktex-console.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/hello
2023-02-18 18:14:10,058+0100 INFO  miktex-console.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/repositories?&releaseState=Stable&orderBy=ranking&take=1&onlySecure=true
2023-02-18 18:14:10,098+0100 INFO  mainwindow - downloading https://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb3-2.9.tar.lzma...
```

Processing `ltxbase` is only confined to this short time period (18:10) - MikTex didn't try it again, though it reports activities around 18:32 . It wasn't updated:

[image: ltxbase screenshot]

**So**, looks like I should ask it to update all ltx-packages?

Comment: AFAIK `texsys.cfg` is part of LaTeX itself. Is is needed to generate a new LaTeX format (see line 162 in `latex.ltx`). Usually it is a *comments only file* `…/tex/latex/base/texsys.cfg` in the main TEXMF root.

Comment: So if MiKTeX package `ltxbase` has been updated, maybe there was a problem with this update. I would first try to rebuild the LaTeX formats. If this fails, I would try to force a reinstall of MiKTeX package `ltxbase`. But I'm not using MiKTeX, I'm TeX Live user.

Comment: Thanks, I see it in latex.ltx. How do I rebuild Latex formats?

Comment: @cabohah, your guess was justified, see my extended EDIT. Thanks for pointing this out for me.

Comment: @cabohah, looks like I'm up and running again. Thanks for paying attention yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this procedure worked:

- have a sleep
- install most `ltx*` packages via MikTex console.

I couldn't select `ltxcmds` together with the other, so I left that for future updates or installs.

---

If that hadn't worked, my next choice would have been:

- restart Windows
- de- and reinstall MikTex.

Idea: Get rid of all locks some processes might have set.

---

[image: selected packages]

[image: result]